# Facebook v2.8 access token without login

Tags: json, facebook

I try to fetch events from a facebook page and it works well with a temporary access token (code below). I've searched lots of QA's for an answer about how to get a permanent access token or something similar.

**There is no user-login on my website, it is just about fetching the JSON - no interaction.**

Then I found this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

to "change" my token into a 60day token but I get an Error:

`Error validating client secret.`

And I can assure you, that my client secret is correct.

So what I have is:

- Page ID, App ID, App Secret

**And what I do is basically this: (works with the temp access token)**

```
$page_id = "xxx";
$app_id = "xxx";
$token = "xxx";
$object = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/".$page_id."/events?fields=id,name&access_token=".$token));


<pre>
  <?php print_r($object); ?>
</pre>
```

What to do now? Did I miss something?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Go use an extended page access token. (Go read up on it in the docs, if that doesn’t mean anything to you.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not about an 'extended page access token' - it's all about the App Token which you can find here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/

This token gives you access to your App-Data.